# bash syntax error for command

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko

I have a list:

```
jos = ['/usr/bin/hive', '-e', "'set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';'"]
```

I will process the list like so

`cmdlines = " ".join(map(lambdas x:("'"+x+"'"), jos))`

I will then push this string in paramiko:

`stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmdlines)`

All paramiko does is allow me to `ssh` into another machine.

I am currently getting the syntax error

`stderr.readlines()` produces

```
[u"bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `from'\n", u"bash: -c: line 0: `'/usr/bin/hive' '-e' ''set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where application_mobile_device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';'''\n"]
```

Not sure what this error means or where it needs to be fixed

Comment: looks like "' '" causes the problem

Comment: @BallPython yea I'm dealing with a few "'" because of the queries. Not sure how to fix this =[

Comment: try to escape them, should work

Comment: `lambda`, not `lambdas`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you initialize `jos`, I notice that you are very careful to use `"..."` instead of `'...'` around the string that contains `'`; but then you throw that caution away when you initialize `cmdlines`:

```
cmdlines = " ".join(map(lambdas x:("'"+x+"'"), jos))
```

Here you just wrap all the strings in `'...'` and put spaces between them. So your actual Bash script (your actual argument to `bash -c`) is:

> `'/usr/bin/hive' '-e' ''set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where application_mobile_device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';''`

when what you really need it to be is:

> `'/usr/bin/hive' '-e' "set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where application_mobile_device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';"`

or even:

> `/usr/bin/hive -e "set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where application_mobile_device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';'"`

(Note: I've also removed some `'`-s around that third string. You had `"'...'"` where you wanted just `"..."`.)

The best fix is probably to do away with the `jos` array. Don't mess around too much with the guts of the Bash script; just set `cmd_lines` directly:

> `cmd_lines = "/usr/bin/hive -e \"set mapred.job.queue.name=exp_dsa; select * from trinity.clickstream where application_mobile_device_id = '59ab' and event_timestamp = '141833140000';\""`